# How can i make an object not reference anything?

Tags: java

I have been asked to make my own linked list without any API. I have a data Array which are my elements, and then my next Array which hold the index references which are used to point to the next value the data array. For example :

```
int nil = -1
Comparable [] data = new Comparable {1, 4, 5, 2, 18, 9}
int [] next = new int {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nil}
```

So 1 in data points to four in data because in the corresponding array spot with 1 in data is 1 in next which is the value which will be used as an index for the next spot in data.

My problem is my nil value. I have been told that setting it to -1 will work to end the list but whenever I try this it gets set to 0 and therefore anything i try will just loop as the end value will then point to the first value. Why does this happen and what can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java reference types can be assigned a `null` reference. [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), a reference type, is a wrapper around the primitive `int`. So if you use it instead, you should be able to use `null`:

```
Integer[] next = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null };
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do this kind of thing with an int?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind  a Linked-List is that you have nodes that point to the next (and previous if it is a doubly linked list) without using any underlying data structure. (You are creating the data-structure.)

```
    public class Node
    {
        public Node Prev { get; set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can build a LinkedList structure that uses the nodes to build up the structure.

```
    public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head = null;
        private Node tail = null;

        public void Add(Node node)
        {
            //Add code...
        }

        public void Remove(Node node)
        {
            //Remoce code...
        }

        //etc...
    }
```